# Spelling correction which feels like flying

Tags: shortcut-keys, ibus, usability, spell-checking

Here is a screen shot of a typo:

[image]

The cursor is at the "..." position.

My dream: I press a magic keyboard short-cut and the spelling correction takes its best guess at correcting the typo.

How to get this dream true?

Background: The screen shot is from Thunderbird, but it should work in all applications.

I type with ten fingers and I want to avoid to take the mouse.

Comment: You might have a better chance of getting a miracle answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com which is for general unix/linux questions unlike this more restricted, ubuntu-specifc site.

Comment: AFAIK unix.stackexchange.com is better suited for command line tools. This is a GUI/Desktop issue.

Comment: You point out an interesting feature! Feature that is missing. I want also to say you that it is software specific (gedit, libreoffice, ...) and/or toolkit specific (GTK+ or qt). I suggest you to open a bug (a feature request in this case) in the GTK bug-tracker

Comment: @mattia.b89 thank you for your positive feedback. I created a issue here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as this feature does not exist at the time of writing, @guettli has opened (under my suggestion) a [bug report](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777639) in the GTK bugtracker

Comment: The bug/feature request as closed as "won't fix". I think the desktop (windows and ubuntu) usage will decrease. And android usage will increase. I am amazingly fast with the android swype keyboard. On android I can swype "uabilty" and the right word will be selectable.  Don't tell me this is no possible on ubuntu desktop. The hard core nerds just don't care for uabiltx. Sooner or later there will some android keyboards available on the device I use. If this device will run ubuntu or not. I don't know.